# Why are all being told to partake of the emblems of the last supper?

Tags: jesus

Luke 22 is a great description of this event. Jesus said, "Keep on doing this in remembrance of me."  It occurred on the night of the Passover, a celebration occurring once a year. Jesus' celebration as well should occur that night, once a year.

A huge problem I see is that all are being told to partake. Why? Luke 22:29-30 is clear on that matter. The covenant was made to those who would sit on thrones, other than Jesus in his kingdom. (Rev 1:6, Rev 20:6) This was the "little flock" (Luke 12:32) who are the ones who will sit on thrones, these are the anointed, the bride of Christ, numbered at 144,000. Thus the "great crowd" (Rev 7:9) of "other sheep" (John 10:16) who are not of that fold should not be partaking. I believe it's a major sin for them to do so.

So Why are all being told to partake?

Comment: I think your theology is getting in the way of the plain reading of Scripture.  The words of Jesus are final - if our theology contradicts the words of Jesus, then there is something wrong with the theology.

Comment: I don't disagree with your post but this should probably be asked on Christianity.SE and directed toward a particular denomination.

Comment: There is no mistake in my op--Luke 22:29-30 is clear on the matter.

Comment: Luke 22:29, 30 is clear but I do not see how that contracts what Jesus said earlier in the same chapter.

Comment: Yoiu will need to explain clearly why you suggest that these two passages contradict!

Comment: @kjw47. Others will observe but not partake. Good Q. It seem some already have voted to close your q, on what basis, I do not know. But it is obvious one is quick to make it about theology.

Comment: There is no logic to this question. Those who believe are exhorted to remember the Lord in his death. Nobody else is invited to do so, in the words of Jesus or in all of scripture. I cannot see what is your problem. It seems to me your are muddled up with a false view of 144,000 but why, is not clear.

Comment: Everything after "*The covenant …*" is the interpretation of some denominations, but definitely not all denominations. Since this question depends upon that information, it makes the question unsuitable for this site. You should determine which denomination(s) hold this view, and then ask the question in Christianity.SE, asking "Why do [denomination] not see a contradiction between Luke 22 and their belief that …?*".

Comment: I don't have a false view of the little flock, only they are the anointed, the bride of Christ= 144,000--They have to be the 144,000 because no man can number the great crowd of other sheep who are not of that fold-Only the little flock will sit on thrones-These are the ones Jesus made that covenant with-Luke 22:29-30

Answer (score 4):

On the contrary, Jesus said,

> Amen, amen, I say to you, unless you eat the flesh of the Son of Man and drink his blood, you do not have life within you. [John 6:53]

Therefore this is for all who would have eternal life.

And this was not to be done once a year according to the Apostles themselves, who did it every day.

> Every day they devoted themselves to meeting together in the temple area and to breaking bread in their homes. [Acts 2:46]

Paul takes it for granted that all Christians will take Communion

> Is not the cup of thanksgiving for which we give thanks a participation in the blood of Christ? And is not the bread that we break a participation in the body of Christ? Because there is one loaf, we, who are many, are one body, for we all share the one loaf. [1 Corinthians 10:16-17]

Comment: Jesus was speaking to the little flock. One body of the little flock. Most back in Jesus day were members of the little flock.

Comment: @kjw47 On what grounds do you argue that most of those in Jesus's day were members of the little flock?

Comment: @kjw47 - why have you based some, unexplained doctrine on a single verse in the NT, viz, Luke 12:32 which is unconnected to Luke 22?

Comment: Only the little flock will sit on thrones.